# Android Studio App not running on Device and Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

App doesn't run on both Emulator and Device on MAC, I only get an error saying client not ready yet.

I tried Invalidating and Restarting Android studio , tried to close app, uninstall, rerun , disabling instant run ,Clean Project, Rebuild , Deleting Gradle but none of these worked.

below is the run log that I'm getting.

$ adb push /Users/username/app/App/build/generalDebug-1.6.1-530966e6.apk /data/local/tmp/com.site.app $ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.site.app” Success

Client not ready yet..

Does anyone know a solution for it?

Answer (score 4):

Are you exporting the activity exported. The activity needs to be exported for adb to use it.

Try adding the exported tag explicitly as shown below:

```
<activity
    android:name=".my.MyActivity"
    android:exported="true"/>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the Android studio and install the latest one.Then go to the

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default settings

update the Android SDK location in settings.

Then boom.... IDE will working as it was working normally.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of tries, I finally resolved it by closing the project and reimporting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. go to tools.
2. navigate Android.
3. click on Enable ADB integration (bear in mind , you have to tick on ADB integration)

Answer (score 0):

Create another virtual device, make sure devices virtual image is available in sdk or download and update. Check laucher activty in manifest and make sure its properly called.